# Is there any idiom or popular phrase that says " be careful of when making a judgement while listening to a news,gossip,rumor...etc from someone

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request

Is there any idiom or popular phrase that says:

> *" be careful of when making a judgement while listening to a news,gossip,rumor...etc from someone"*

Because what they say can be biased, probably not true, and it's up to you to make the correct decision.

Comment: To "take with a pinch of salt" implies scepticism.

Comment: not "*a* news", "*a* gossip".   No article there.  Just "news", "gossip".

Answer (score 3):

The most common phrase to describe this is

> Don't believe everything that you hear.

You can substitute "read" or "see on TV" if you wish.

It's actually a quote from the [bible](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20John%204&version=MSG), and is a popular subject for Facebook instant-wisdom images like [these](http://quotesgram.com/dont-believe-everything-you-hear-quotes/)

Answer (score 1):

You may use the expression:

***Don't***  ***[jump to conclusions/leap to conclusions](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/jump+to+conclusions)***:

> Fig. to judge or decide something without having all the facts; to reach unwarranted conclusions. (See also rush to conclusions.) *Now don't jump to conclusions. Wait until you hear what I have to say. Please find out all the facts so you won't leap to conclusions.*